# How set a MS Project to choose between two resources when leveling

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-server-2016

The company has two welders that are equal in skill and knowledge, we wish to set them as a resource to a same task.

And we already did:

On the field resource name, we put both "Richard;Pablo"

But in this way, after the leveling of resources, they share, at the same time, the work on the task. We wish that one of this two welders make all the task by himself, and the leveling tool be able to choose between them.

I already try using operators, to set the field resource name as "Richard" or "Pablo". But this field doesn't accept this type of argument.

[Assigning as Resource Group rather than a resource](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/26287126-711a-41d7-afa8-653e19884212/assigning-as-resource-group-rather-than-a-resource?forum=projectprofessional2010general)

This guy seem to have a answer, although is a quite short explanation, and i couldn't make work.

I would realy apreciate any help on this.